# How to filter multiple values and nulls in prisma

Tags: javascript, prisma

Im having some trouble defining a query with prisma. When selecting values from a table with 2 different values, lets say name and age, how can I filter that table with name equals to "John" or null, and age equals to 22 or null?

Edit : trying to provide some code for some context, here is something I tried :

```
const results = await prisma.myModel.findMany({
  where: {
    OR: [
      {
        name: {
          in: ["John", null], // Include "John" and NULL names
        },
        age: {
          in: [22, null], // Include ages 22 and NULL
        },
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

However, the in statement, according to the prima documentation, excludes all nulls, therefore the query will not contain the NULL entries

Comment: What have you tried, where is your code?

Comment: I added some code for more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is should be the following:

```js
const whereNameAndAgeIs = Prisma.validator<Prisma.UserWhereInput>()({
  AND: [{
    OR: [{
      name: 'John'
    }, {
      name: null
    }],
  }, {
    OR: [{
      age: 22,
    }, {
      age: null
    }],
  }],
})
```

Check out the Prisma docs:

- https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#where
- https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference?query=AND&page=1#and

Comment: I will give it a try and come back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Worked, thank you